# How can I test my natural language processing model with "real" cases?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, text-classification

I am introducing myself to Natural Languaje Processing and artificial neural networks and I have followed this wonderful [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/)
Once finished it, I would like to know if there is any way to test the model with phrases that I can invent, (That film entertained me a lot) for example.
Because it is very good to know the percentage of success on the test set, but I want to know how to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
test_phrase = 'That film entertained me a lot'
example = vectorizer.transform([test_phrase])
print(test_phrase + ' was classified as ' + str(classifier.predict(example)))
```

Comment: I believe that the text would need to be tokenized first.

Comment: u yeah sorry I didn't look at the source data properly; I will do it now

Comment: Sorry, I'm little lost, what do you mean by the classifier,is the keras model?

Comment: classifier is the model you've just defined and trained here: `classifier = LogisticRegression()` + `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)`. vectorizer is an instance of a CountVectorizer() that was used to transform your dataset into a set of tokens that can be used for training

Comment: And can I do the same with the Keras model here?
`model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,
                            epochs=epochs, batch_size=10,
                            verbose=False)
    grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=param_grid,
                              cv=4, verbose=1, n_iter=5)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)`